# A confusion about the sentence "any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails."

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

[temp.deduct.type#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#2)

> In some cases, the deduction is done using a single set of types P and A, in other cases, there will be a set of corresponding types P and A. Type deduction is done independently for each P/A pair, and the deduced template argument values are then combined. If type deduction cannot be done for any P/A pair, or if for any pair the deduction leads to more than one possible set of deduced values, or if different pairs yield different deduced values, or if **any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails**.

Consider the above sentence, whose the  `template argument` belong  to? Does it refer to template arguments of the template which the type `P` origin from , or that of a template that P naming?  Through reading this sentence, I can't determine which it refers to.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct Test{};
template<typename T, typename U = T>
void func(Test<T>){}
int main(){
  func(Test<char, char>{});
}
```

#### Question 1

In other words, the `template argument` in above sentence refer to that for function template `func` or that for class template `Test`? Both template need `template argument` to form a specialization.

#### Question 2

If `template argument` refer to class template `Test`'s, that is,
For P/A pair , namely `Test<T>` / `Test<char, char>`, The process compares `T` with `char`, then the deduced value for `T` is `char`, since there's no any other `Pi` in template-argument-list of `P`, So there is nothing else to be deduced. After deduction performed for each `Pi` that participates in template argument deduction, there's a second template parameter of `Test` remain no template argument and the value for it is neither `deduced` or `explicitly specified`, The template argument is obtained from `default argument`, So Does the emphasized paragraph not cover this case?(**Obtain from default arguments means the way to get template argument value is neither through deduced nor explicitly specified**). So the deduction would fails? I think it does not fail. If I misunderstand about what is template argument deduction success, please point it out.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#1
"... be deduced from the use OR OBTAINED from default template-arguments". A template argument is not to subject for deduction if it is default template argument.

Comment: @nicolai Do you mean the rules in [temp.deduct] is supplement to all deduction rules?

Comment: @nicolai It sounds like [temp.deduct#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#5) applied to substitution of all kind of deduction, However It is clear to say "any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, nor obtained from default argument, template argument deduction fails ", Do you agree?

Comment: I think no deduction is required for default template arguments, therefore we can't say that deduction failed.

Comment: @nicolai Yes, `no deduction is required for default template arguments`, so the template argument remains **neither deduced** nor **explicitly specified**

Comment: @jackX would default argument specification be considered a substitution for that? U equals to T and T would be either deduced or explicitly specified?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The whole process you said, I think it's the wording `obtain from default argument` which is explicitly given in [temp.deduct]. So, It should neither be called deduced or explicitly specified.